# Beanshell - Class MongoClient not found in namespace

Tags: java, mongodb, import, package, beanshell

I am experimenting with bean shell interpreter, but it seems every time I import a package/class; I get the same error.

It could be because the package is not downloaded but I am not sure how I can do that? any input would be appreciated.

I am using Linux/Ubuntu.

Example below:

```
bsh % import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
bsh % MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );

OUTPUT:
// Error: EvalError: Typed variable declaration : Class: MongoClient not found in namespace : at Line: 2 : in file: <unknown file> : MongoClient
```

Comment: This is an interpretor so it just executes

Comment: Check if it exists using bsh % which( com.mongodb.MongoClient );

Comment: bsh % which(com.mongodb.MongoClient);
// Error: EvalError: Class or variable not found: com.mongodb.MongoClient : at Line: 3 : in file: <unknown file> : com .mongodb .MongoClient

Comment: It seems like it does not exist even though i have clearly imported it. Not sure how i could get it to exist.